# SSRS Decimal format only when number is there

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I need to write a report in SSRS

I need the numbers to display as listed below

0.3555 is displayed as 0.35

0 is displayed as 0 Instead I get 0.00

So far I have =FormatNumber(Fields!Day3.Value, 2) to only have two decimal but now I need it to be 0 when there is no decimal How do I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSRS How do i force number to two decimal numbers if it is not 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74618507/ssrs-how-do-i-force-number-to-two-decimal-numbers-if-it-is-not-0)

Answer (score 0):

The INT function can be used in an IIF to check if the number needs a decimal and return the places to return for the FormatNumber function.

```
=FormatNumber(
                Fields!Day3.Value, 
                IIF(Fields!Day3.Value = INT(Fields!Day3.Value), 0, 2)
            )
```

INT truncates the decimal. IF the number = INT(number), then it returns 0 for the number of places for the FormatNumber. 5.5 would return 2 while 8 would have 0 places.

Answer (score 0):

On the field properties you can customize the format.

The first expression hides zeroes and also displays non zero decimals

The second expression displays zeroes and also displays non zero decimals

The third expression shows always 2 decimals for all numbers excluding zero

[image]

Comment: For those who cannot view the image, here are the format expressions:
1.) 0.##;-0.##;#
2.) 0.##;-0.##;0
3.) iif(Fields!num1.Value=0,"0","0.00")

Examples:
1.23 -> 1.23/1.23/1.23;
0.00 -> [None]/0/0;
0.35 -> 0.35/0.35/0.35;
0.10 -> 0.1/0.1/0.10;
-53.00 -> -53/-53/-53.00